# Lucene wildcard search

Tags: search, lucene, wildcard, kibana

I've got data that looks like this:

`CK/YZfB6XUmSOSM3IJqM2Q; Response code: 404. Elapsed: 0ms. Request: GET /marketing`
`4kk/TiKjYU2JY0L2N14QLg; Response code: 200. Elapsed: 10ms. Request: GET /api/monitor`
`vhXVsw4sBk69qv7dGE8JYw; Response code: 404. Elapsed: 0ms. Request: GET /graph-statistics`
`4kk/TiKjYW2JY0L2N14QLg; Response code: 200. Elapsed: 10ms. Request: GET /api/monitor`

I'm trying to query/filter it out so I only remain with the 4xx responses.

I've read the documentation regarding [wildcards](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/5.5/query-dsl-query-string-query.html#_wildcards), so I'd expect at least one of the following queries to work (this is as written in Kibana):

```
message: "Response code: 4??"
message: 4??.
message: "Response code: 4*"
```

Here's how these look in JSON, in case escaping matters (I've enumerated all the 3 queries in the same JSON for brevity):

```json
"filter" : [],
"query" : {
 "query_string" : {
  "query" : "message: \"Response code: 4??\"",
  "query" : "message: 4??.",
  "query" : "message: \"Response code: 4*\"",
  "analyze_wildcard" : true
 }
},
```

I've had no luck so far and I'm running out of ideas...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on your question, the text appears to be indexed in the field **message**.
If you want your query to return only 4XX responses, then try the below query.

```
message: (Response AND code AND 4??)
```

This query is essentially asking lucene to get records that have the words **response**, **code** and **4xx** in them.
I tested against the following case, where your record might contain 400 as part of Elapsed time.

> ......... Response code:200 Elapsed:404ms.......

But the query works fine and doesn't return these results as the 404 is having **ms** as suffix. So, this doesn't match with your search for **4??**.

Also, you might have to check for how the field is indexed in your collection. Is it stored as text or string?
In your code example, you have not escaped **:** which is a special character in lucene.

Note: this query checks for presence of these keywords in text but nor necessarily in the given order

Comment: this query seems to search for messages that have _exactly_ that string (with "AND"s), instead of adding new search terms through the AND keyword...

Comment: I have edited to remove the quotes and use braces. Are you running the queries through any lucene API or Kibana UI?

Comment: this is definitely the closest I've got so far! the only remaining (slight) issue is that it also matches random 4xx in the Guids that sit in front of the message; I guess that's because I can't enforce the keywords presence order? any way to go around this?

Comment: May be you should try to search with regular expression syntax to match it in required format and given order